# Sharing Windows PC Internet via USB cable

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

I cannot see any option to share My Windows PC Internet via USB cable.

How can I share PC internet to phone via USB? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

what do you want to do, usb is not capable of sharing INTERNET.

If you are referring to sharing files, they you don't need usb, if you have wifi, where both your pc and phone connect, preferably a private home wifi.

to use the ftp on wifi: phone to pc, set sharing on phone, and pc will ftp. while pc to phone,  set sharing on a folder and use ftp or file explorer like es-file explorer to folder. I use this all the time to transfer photos. es if i want to post to intsagram from a digital photo(after transfer from camera to pc)

Comment: USB is capable of sharing internet. See the tethering and reverse tethering tags.